# My INDEX MATCH array function only returns #N/A on Excel 2010

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match

I am using the following formula:

```
{=INDEX(PlateDetails[Height],MATCH(1,('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$30000=PlateDetails[MRS Plate ID])*('Raw Data'!$C$2:$C$30000=PlateDetails[Room Name])*('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$30000=PlateDetails[Place Location]),0))}
```

My aim is to match three columns (Plate ID, Room Name, Place Location) on two different tabs (Plate details and Raw Data), and return the corresponding value in column Height. However it only returns #N/A.

Can someone help please?

Comment: You're trying to match against entire columns of your PlateDetails table, rather than one row at a time.

Comment: So I changed it and it started working, but it was changing the row number in the formula as it went down my columns, so after a while it gave me #na again. I have now changed it to this (see below) but it's returning #NA again

Comment: `code` =INDEX('Plate details'!E$2:E$270,MATCH(1,('Raw Data'!$A$2:$A$30000='Plate details'!A$2:A$270)*('Raw Data'!$C$2:$C$30000='Plate details'!C$2:C$270)*('Raw Data'!$G$2:$G$30000='Plate details'!D$2:D$270),0))

Comment: @AnnyDiSomma nope that's not correct, what @Rory Sir has mentioned, you need to compare a cell. So the formula, will be like `=INDEX('Plate details'!E$2:E$270,MATCH(1,('Raw Data'!$A2='Plate details'!A$2:A$270)*('Raw Data'!$C2='Plate details'!C$2:C$270)*('Raw Data'!$G2='Plate details'!D$2:D$270),0)) `

Comment: @AnnyDiSomma Thank you madam, for sharin the feedback!